# Can't Compile C++ Code With Sleep() on Linux - Which Library to Include?

Tags: c++, linux, sleep

I'm trying to compile some code that uses the line:

```
Sleep(10);
```

In my IDE, all I have to do is either write:

```
using namespace std;
```

or

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

and it compiles fine!

However, when compiling via the command line on Linux, everything is *not* OK. The compiler tells me that `Sleep` is undefined. I compile using:

```
g++ -lglut -lGL -lm -o PROGRAM.exe PROGRAM.cpp
```

Other code I have written that does not use `Sleep` compiles fine in this way.

What library do I need to supply to the linker (with `-l`) to get the `Sleep` function recognized?

Comment: you have a typo: `man 3 sleep`

Comment: Uhh, come again? It compiles fine in my IDE

Comment: `Sleep` is a windows system call. It does not exist in Linux. You need to use `sleep` or `usleep`. If you want code that compiles on both, you probably want to write a wrapper function for one or t'other.

Comment: Gotcha. I have tried to make a wrapper like so: #ifdef _WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#define Sleep(x) usleep((x)*1000)
#endif

However, my problem is, usleep is undefined and thus won't compile on Windows despite me using the unistd header. I thought it was included in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Sleep` is a windows function.  On Unix use `usleep`.  Note that `usleep` takes microseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Mats Petersson answered my question, but this was also helpful and concise. I simply switched to usleep() and adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

C++11 brings concurrency and a sleep function to the standard library. `Sleep` and `usleep` are *not* portable. Use the sleep utility in the standard library instead.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
}
```

Here the C++14 [standard literal `s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s) for seconds is also used (brought in using the namespace `std::literals`). `10s` is equivalent to [`std::chrono::seconds(10)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

There are corresponding standard literals for other time durations as well, e.g. `ms`, `us` and `ns`.

No libraries need to be supplied to the linker using what's above.

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b697fed3dac1a661)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, if C++11 is available this is the best way to go.

Comment: @japreiss As C++11 is the latest standard of the language (not a draft anymore) and no specific requirement for C++03/98 support is mentioned, I will assume that there is no reason to *not* use the latest standard.

Comment: Actually, C++14 might be the current standard as of now. From **isocpp.org:** *"As of August 2014, C++14 has completed its final international ballot and will be published later this year."*

Answer (score 1):

To supply portability you necessarily use:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
    Sleep(10);
#else
    sleep(10);
#endif
```

Otherwise, if you have C++11, consider @Snps's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lowercase `s` instead of uppercase `S` .Your function name will be `sleep()` instead of `Sleep()`.